# MS Edge closing links that are opened with shortcut ctrl + mouse click

Tags: browser, shortcuts, microsoft-edge, hyperlink

I want to open the links on a webpage (adjacent to the one in use but not switch to it immediately), by using the universal shortcut for the same viz, Keyboard Control Key + Mouse Click (Left / Middle) but when I do that in MS Edge browser, it keeps closing the new tab, which is created in the background, adjacent to the current tab (right side). I can see the new tab getting generated but as soon as it opens, Edge closes it for some reason.
This is a basic operation that can be performed on all browsers since the dawn of internet browsing. I was using Firefox and Chrome all this while and started using Edge only recently only to find this nagging problem.
I went to Edge settings and couldn't find anything pertaining to the issue. A similar setting on Firefox would be in Tab settings Toggle -> "When you open a link, image or media in a new tab, switch to it immediately".
I then searched on Google and Bing but was surprised not to find any solution to this issue. In the meanwhile I am using this as an alternative -> Mouse Right click -> Open Link in New Tab
Am I the only one with this issue or am I the only one wanting to use Edge this way?
TY

Comment: If you want to switch to the new tab, open the link with ctrl+shift+click or shift+wheelclick

Comment: @Tuor "Shift+Wheelclick" did open the tab, but it also made the new tab active instead of going in the background as desired, and "Ctrl+Shift+Click"(Left/Middle[Wheelclick]) does the same as the issue, disappears immediately upon creation. Thank you for the input. (Y)

Comment: "A similar setting on Firefox would be in Tab settings Toggle -> "When you open a link, image or media in a new tab, switch to it immediately"."      Seemed like that's what you were looking for

Comment: The emphasis was on that particular Firefox's "Tab" Setting and as is the feature has the "Toggle" option. What I want to achieve is what is mentioned in the problem description. Sorry for the confusion but thank you for your input.

Comment: Got it. good luck